# Divs still have spaces even though margin and padding is zero

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue where I cannot remove the spaces between divs.  I've included my markup and css and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kW5uW/12/

Despite having set margin and `padding` to zero, I still see spaces in between the divs, how can I remove this?  I want all the boxes to be right next to each other.

CSS and Markup:

```css
.segment {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="segment"></div>
  <div class="segment"></div>
  <div class="segment"></div>
  <div class="segment"></div>
  <div class="segment"></div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space. One way to fix this is to just remove the white space between the divs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="segment"></div><div class="segment"></div><div class="segment"></div><div class="segment"></div><div class="segment"></div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kW5uW/14/)**

You could also:

- Float them left (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/B2mtU/)**)
- Set the font size on the parent div to zero (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j2rVT/)**)
- Take up the white space with HTML comments (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8s3JJ/)**)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this, by changing your `segment` class `CSS` to the following:

```
.segment {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```